# Load video without player controls (mediaelement.js)

Tags: jquery, mediaelement.js

I would have thought this is a really easy/obvious fix but can't figure it out as much as I've tried...

Is there any way so that when a video is loaded on a page (simply loaded, no interaction or clicking play) that the controls for the video appear hidden.  Only when you click on the poster image (play) will the controls appear and then behave as expected? I would if possible also like to decrease the delay of time it takes to show/hide controls..

Thanks for any help in advance!